# ffmpeg with php not completed if file size > 5mb

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to upload videos to my server,

I've tested on 1MB file and another one 5MB and it is working correctly, but then I've tested on 6MB and 50MB file and it try to upload but still with "processing" status with no change.

Here is the code which I use

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ../uploadedvideo/".$image_name." -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 200 -r 15 -s 240x180 -fs 314572800 -f flv ../uploadedvideo/".$image_namew.".flv");
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Connection timeout most likely, server will disconnect after a certain amount of time if a response is not sent back.

Comment: Long running processes should not be handled in requests like this, offload it to a background task.

Comment: There is also a configurable upload size limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @reptilicus I think that's the right answer, but I also suggest doing the encoding in a separate process. It can be done with sending a message to a work queue, and worker code listening to that queue.

Comment: @reptilicus I'm still beginner with ffmpeg, how to make the process run in the background task ?

Comment: @YaşarŞentürk How can we do that? Is there any tutorial for this specific point?

Comment: @YasserHossam, you can upload the file as you are doing already. You can have a message queue system, like RabbitMQ. You can submit a message into a queue on RabbitMQ. That message can have information about the file, and parameters to ffmpeg. You can write another script that listens the same queue on RabbitMQ, and when it gets the message, you can execute the ffmpeg. See here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html